# How to group apps in Metro in a similar way to a web app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-10

As a web developer, when I have multiple sites that are related by a common theme or common department, I have a home page that has links to the different sites. For example, there may be a site for reports (output to pdf or excel), another for inputting and editing sales data, and yet another for real-time tracking. Normally these links are in a header or sidebar which is static and can be accessed by all associated apps.

I'm reading about Metro/Modern apps now. I'll be trying to make my first Metro app soon. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to have (at least the illusion) of accessing 3 different apps through 1 app. So the user, just as in the web app, goes to one place.

If so, does anyone have any resources they can share?

Answer (score 0):

To include multiple apps in the same frame they would need to all be part of the same app.

If you want links to jump between apps then you can create a protocol association to launch into the apps. This can include an arbitrary string so you can deep link rather than going just to the opening page.

On Windows 8.1 this connection is one-way: launching the protocol is fire-and-forget. The launching app doesn't get any feedback or results from the launched app.

Windows 10 adds the ability to return results to use the app as a service. I think this sounds more like what you are looking for.

See [Auto-launching with file and URI associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779673.aspx) on MSDN and the Build session [App-to-App Communication: Building a Web of Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-765)

Answer (score 0):

actually in Windows Universal app it's the same Approach. You got your app, and different pages where you could navigate back and forth... each page with it's unique look depending on your Need.

The user will open one app to Access all...

searching a bit in the net will Show you a lot of examples... Topic: Navigation, LiveCylcles, ...